# Combining multiple mosaics into single one using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, mosaic, orthophoto, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I collected 615 images with Phantom 4dji. My computer couldn't process all of them together on Agisoft Photoscan, so I separated my photos by area, making five orthophotos.
My goal is to combine all of these 5 orthopotos into a single one to make a mosaic of the hole area. 
First I was thinking on making it on Agisoft but then I got an error: "SSL support not available". So, I tried in Arcmap following this [tutorial](https://www.edc.uri.edu/blog/creating-mosaic-dataset-orthophotos), otherwise my mosaic ends up having black gaps between the orthophotos:

[image: Mosaic on Arcmap 10.5]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I would create mosaic dataset, not mosaic to new raster, using original 615 of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running the build footprints tool before completing the mosaic. This should effectively remove the black "NO DATA" borders around the individual image mosaics before completely the mosaic of all the images together.

ESRI has a pretty good explanation of the workflow here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012496

The key to this method is understanding what the values of the black border are.
So use the identify tool - blue "i" - to check the value of the border you want to remove. Then run the "Build Footprints" tool on each of your initially mosaicked datasets, then run through your mosaic workflow on the processed images.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy I found the solution today. When I run the last step "Build Overviews" my mosaic got like a chess stamp, so I decided to not do it anymore and did everything again, following the steps until Mosaic "Dataset Properties".
Today I found in [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/189456-build-overviews-for-a-mosaic-generates-blackwhile-tiles) that if I modified a parameter in "Environments" the black gaps and the chess stamp would desapear